# download_and_prepare() rock_paper_scissors comes with error

Tags: python

Hei,
I try to use dataset "rock_paper_scissors" from tensorflow_datasets.But it does not work when download and prepares the dataset, even after I have installed tfds-nightly.

The main part of the codes are written like this:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
hands_builder = tfds.builder("rock_paper_scissors")
hands_builder.download_and_prepare()
```

**Errors:

```
TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got WindowsGPath('C:\\Users\\Wilso\\tensorflow_datasets\\downloads\\download.tensorflow.org_rpswkA0RDlYQq0ExTYSutVLV0RD6uF6ByMRei_4e51yGU8.zip')
```

versions relative to the codes are:

```
tensorflow-gpu: 2.1.0
tensorflow_datasets: 3.0.0
tfds-nightly : 4.6.0

operating system: Windows-10
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: Hi @ZhangWei, kindly upgrade the version of `tensorflow` >=`2.4` or downgrade the version of `tfds-nightly` to `4.1.0.dev202012280107` to avoid the error. Please find the gist [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/c1c0849ac34f8a5c10d24426ff3bddb5/untitled179.ipynb). Thank you!